# random.choices and if/else statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I am trying to make a list so that you will have a name, their behavior and an action. I just don't seem to get my `if/else` statement to work. It only picks my `else`. Never my `if` even though that should have a higher probability. This is my code:

```
import random

Names = ['john', 'james', 'dave', 'ryan']
behaviour = ['good', 'bad']
good = ['candy', 'presents', 'hug']
bad = ['get coal', ' have to stand in the corner']
for i in Names:
    n = random.choices(behaviour,weights=(3,1))
    k = random.choice(bad)
    if n=='good':
         print('{} was good this year therefor they get {}'.format(i,random.choice(good)))
    else:
         print('{} was bad this year therefor they {}'.format(i,random.choice(bad)))
```

all my things are just name was bad this year therefore they get and then either coal or the corner.....

Comment: Try doing `print(n)` and you'll find the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

> `random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)`
>
> Return a k sized **list** of elements

It will return a *list*, but you're comparing it to a single string `'good'` - they will never be the same and there it always picks the `else` block.

You could, for example:

```
    if n == ['good']:
         print('{} was good this year therefor they get {}'.format(i,random.choice(good)))
    else:
         print('{} was bad this year therefor they {}'.format(i,random.choice(bad)))
```

Or:

```
    if n[0] == 'good':
```

Comment: Happy to help, if you think any of the answers is good enough, please accept it with the checkmark so that the question is marked answered and others can find it as a being solved.

Answer (score 2):

That's because [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) returns a ***list***, therefore it'll never be equal to a ***string*** (e.g. `'good'`).

Change it to:

```
n = random.choices(behaviour, weights=(3,1))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Random.choices yields a list with one member. To do a comparison against the string "good" you need to index to that item with n[0]

```
if n[0]=='good':
         print('{} was good this year therefor they get {}'.format(i,random.choice(good)))
```

I find it's helpful to throw a print statement to compare variables and verify they are what i think they are. It's a good way to test for problems. A test print like this

```
print(n, 'good', n=='good', str(n)=='good')
```

before the if statements gives this output

```
['good'] good False False
```

which is fairly instructive as to what the problem is.